# Multiple keys query in IndexedDB (Similar to OR in sql)

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have store with multiEntry index on tags.

```
{ tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3' ] }
```

And i have query that also list of tags.

```
[ 'tag2', 'tag1', 'tag4' ]
```

I need to get all records which contain one of tag in query (Similar to SQL OR statement).

Currently I cannot find any other solution except iterate over tags in query and search by the each tag in the store.

Is there any better solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve all results with one query except with iteration. You can optimize the search result by opening a index from the lowest value to the highest:

```
IDBKeyRange.bound ('tag1', 'tag4');
```

Other Indexed-Db feature you can use is to open multiple queries and combine the result when the queries complete. This way would be much faster than the iteration.

Comment: Thank you, with multiple queries I can fall into some limits, do you have maybe link to documentation where described expected behavior/limits of using multiple queries

Comment: No that would be limitation by browser so i would recommend you to do some test by yourself to see what works.

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB has only range query as Deni Mf answered.

OR query is simply union of multiple queries. That may be OK.

If you want efficient query, you have to iterate the cursor and seek the cursor position as necessary. Using [my library](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/getting-started.html), it will be

```
tags = ['tag2', 'tag1', 'tag4'];
tags.sort();
iter = new ydn.db.KeyIterator('store name', 'tags', IDBKeyRange.bound(tags[0], tags[tags.length-1]);
keys = [];
i = 0; 
var req = db.open(iter, function(cursor) {
  if (tags.indexOf(cursor.indexKey()) >= 0) {
      // we got the result
     if (keys.indexOf(cursor.key()) == -1) { // remove duplicate
       keys.push(cursor.key());
     }
  } else {
     return tags[++i]; // jump to next index position.
  }
);

req.done(function() {
  db.list('store name', keys).done(function(results) {
     console.log(results);
   }
});
```

Notice that the algorithm has no false positive retrieval. Key only query is performed first, so that we don't waste on de-serilization. The results is retrieved only we get all the primary keys after removing deplicates.

Comment: all keys in indexeddb are sorted. support you have thousand records tag with 'tag3', skipping them helps run faster. yes, you can replace IDBKeyRange with ydn.db.KeyRange. ydn.db.KeyRange is used for WebSQL or localStorage.