# How to get multiple key value from IndexedDb objectstore

Tags: angularjs, indexeddb

Can somebody suggest how to get multiple key value from IndexedDB objectstore ? I have done multiple options, but didn't work none.
Created indexedDb here

```
$provide.value('dbModel', {
        name: 'TestDB',
        version: '1',
        instance: {},
        objectStoreName: {
            dashboards: 'Appointment'
        },
        upgrade: function (e) {
            var db = e.target.result;
            if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('Appointment')) {
                var calendarobj = db.createObjectStore('Appointment', {
                    keyPath: 'AppointmentId'
                });
                calendarobj.createIndex("AppointmentId", "AppointmentId", { multiEntry: true });
            }
        }
    });
```

And the Data looks like

```
KeyPath-AppointmentId             Value
=====================             =====
1                                 Test 1
2                                 Test 2
3                                 Test 3
```

I have getObjectStore method to get the objectstorename instance.

```
getObjectStore: function (objectStoreName, mode) {
            var modeact = mode || _db.transactionTypes.readonly;
            var txn = _db.instance.transaction(objectStoreName, modeact);
            var store = txn.objectStore(objectStoreName);

            return store;
        }


var keys = [1,2]; // Want to get the First two record which has value 'Test 1' and 'Test 2'
var store = _db.getObjectStore(objectStoreName);
var tagIndex = store.index(store.keyPath); //AppointmentId

var request = tagIndex.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(keys));
//var request = tagIndex.get(keys);

request.onsuccess = function (event) {
                console.log(event.result);
}
```

Comment: Please add a comment when you down vote. So that I can improve my question.

Answer (score 5):

Using `[1, 2]` as you do won't work - that's a key which happens to be an array with two members. Indexed DB currently doesn't understand using lists or sets of keys for querying.

You have a handful of options:

1 - Issue two get requests in parallel. (Since the order is guaranteed, the second request will finish after the first and you know both results will have been returned.)

```
var results = [];
store.get(1).onsuccess = function(e) {
  results.push(e.target.result);
};
store.get(2).onsuccess = function(e) {
  results.push(e.target.result);

  // results will have the values
};
```

2 - Use a cursor and a range:

```
var results = [];
store.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.bound(1, 2)).onsuccess = function(e) {
  var cursor = e.target.result;
  if (cursor) {
    results.push(cursor.value);
    cursor.continue();
  } else {
    // results will have the values
  }
};
```

3 - Use getAll with a range (newer browsers only - fall back to a cursor if not available)

```
store.getAll(IDBKeyRange.bound(1, 2)).onsuccess = function(e) {
  // e.target.result will have the entries
};
```

Note that in options 2 and 3 which use a range you would also get a records with a key of `1.5` if one existed.

Answer (score 2):

This could be duplicated with [Multiple keys query in IndexedDB (Similar to OR in sql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146671/multiple-keys-query-in-indexeddb-similar-to-or-in-sql/61473066#61473066), but I have no permission to report duplication, so I would post the answer again. Hope it helps.

## Use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

```js
// [store]: object store
// [keys]: array of keys
// return: An object of key-value pairs
const get = (store, keys) =>
  Promise.all(
    keys.map(
      (key) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const request = store.get(key);
          request.onsuccess = ({ target: { result } }) => resolve(result);
          request.onerror = ({ target: { error } }) => reject(error);
        })
    )
  ).then((values) =>
    keys.reduce(
      (result, key, index) => ((result[key] = values[index]), result),
      {}
    )
  );
```

## Example

```js
const request = indexedDB.open("test");
request.onupgradeneeded = ({ target: { result: db } }) => {
  db.createObjectStore("settings").transaction.oncomplete = ({
    target: { db },
  }) => {
    const store = db
      .transaction("settings", "readwrite")
      .objectStore("settings");
    store.add(123, "foo");
    store.add(456, "bar");
  };
};
request.onsuccess = ({ target: { result: db } }) => {
  get(db.transaction("settings").objectStore("settings"), [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "buz",
  ]).then(console.log); // {foo: 123, bar: 456, buz: undefined}
};
```