# IndexedDB - Microsoft Edge .getAll method

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, indexeddb

Just recently I have been playing around with IndexedDB - using primarily Google Chrome as my debugging tool. Unfortunately enough I have pretty quickly stumbled upon an issue related strictly to incompatibility between browsers - Edge does not seem to support [.getAll method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/getAll) on IDBObjectStore interface, 
heck the .get method seems to be pretty tricky too - all my attempts so far have resulted in the following error message:

> Unable to get property 'message' of undefined or null reference

Using the below code:

```
var db;
function estabilishConnection(callback) {
    var req = indexedDB.open('database', 1);
    req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        db = evt.target.result;
        callback();
    }
    req.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {
        var target = evt.currentTarget;
        var store = target.result.createObjectStore('object', {autoIncrement: true});
        store.add("sample1");
        store.add("sample2");
        store.add("sample3");
    }
}

function retrieveItems() {
    var transaction = db.transaction("object", "readonly");
    var handler = transaction.objectStore("object");

    var countRequest = handler.count();
    var total; 
    countRequest.onsuccess = function() {
        total = countRequest.result;
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            var get = handler.get(i);
            console.log(get);
        }
    }
}

estabilishConnection(function(evt) {
    retrieveItems()
});
```

My questions would be:

a) what would be the most appropriate way to implement the .getAll method without having to rely on third party libraries such as Dexie.js? I assume that even if iterating through all the available objects had worked, it still would not have been the wisest idea in terms of performance.

b) how to get the get method to work in Edge
-- resolved it already alone, somehow the following snippet worked out, getting all values though remains, as for now, a mystery to me :|

```
db.transaction('object').objectStore('object').get(1).onsuccess = function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.result);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests that the handler variable is null. Are you sure you are waiting to start a new transaction until after the upgrade handler completed? One way to be sure would be to ensure the database open request has settled. From the looks of it, your code doesn't do that. To wait, do something like:

```
var openRequest = indexedDB.open...;
openRequest.onsuccess = function() {
  var db = openRequest.result;
  var handle = db.transaction...;
  // ...
};
```

Actually, I have no idea why are you calling handler.get in that manner. There is no IDBTransaction.prototype.get method.

Also, you might want to look into promises to help you structure the flow more clearly. Here is an example:

```
 function open(name, version, upgradeHandler) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var request = indexedDB.open(name,version);
      request.onupgradeneeded = upgradeHandler;
      request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
      request.onerror = () => reject(request.error);
   });
 }

 function myUgpradeHandler(event) {
   var db = event.target.result;
   var store = db.createObjectStore(...);
 }

 function getItems(db) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var tx = db.transaction(...);
      var request = tx.getAll();
      request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
      request.onerror = () => reject(request.error);
   });
 }

 async function foo() {
   var db = await open(name, version, myUpgradeHandler);
   var items = await getItems(db);
   for(var item of items) {
     console.log(item);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I am officialy a dummie, found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940722/how-to-get-multiple-key-value-from-indexeddb-objectstore), I have absolutely no clue how I managed to miss it when searching for the solution earlier. Use [IDBCursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor) interface instead. Here is the solution in code in case someone had a similar issue.

```
var retrievedItems = [];
    db.transaction('object').objectStore('object').openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if(cursor) {
        retrievedItems.push(cursor.value);
        cursor.continue();
    } else {
        // no more keys remaining
        console.log(retrievedItems);
    }
};
```

Comment: If you'd rather use getAll, here is a shim https://github.com/dumbmatter/IndexedDB-getAll-shim - the implementation is basically the same as your code, but it would allow you to transparently use the native implementation of getAll in non-Edge browsers, which will be faster.